# how to exclude django hstore field in admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, hstore, django-hstore

The standard approach in `admin.py` by defining class:

```
exclude = ('some_hstore_field', )
```

does not work.

I manage to get expected result by specifying explicit `fields` but would like rather exclude the one I don't need, than specify all the other needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have in your model hstore field called `facilities`:

```
facilities = hstore.DictionaryField(schema=HSTORE_SCHEMA)
```

then you **CAN NOT** just write:

```
exclude = ('some_non_hstore_field', 'facilities')
```

Assuming your hstore schema looks something like that:

```
HSTORE_SCHEMA = [
    {
        "name": "vegetarian_menu",
        "class": "BooleanField",
        "kwargs": {
            "default": False,
            "verbose_name": "vegetarian menu"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "vegan_menu",
        "class": "BooleanField",
        "kwargs": {
            "default": False,
            "verbose_name": "vegan menu"
        }
    }
]
```

You have to exclude each of subfield by its name, e.g:

```
exclude = ('some_non_hstore_field', 'vegetarian_menu', 'vegan_menu')
```

you can do it like this:

```
exclude = tuple(['some_non_hstore_field'] + [field['name'] for field in HSTORE_SCHEMA])
```

or like this - using meta of class field:

```
exclude = tuple(['some_non_hstore_field'] + [field['name'] for field in YourModel._meta.get_field_by_name('facilities')[0].schema])
```

The same applies for `readonly_fields`